# Swing window arbitrarily adding margins in Windows and Linux, but not Mac

Tags: java, swing

For a school project, I have to make a Library management app in Java. Since, Reeder for Mac came out recently, I thought I might try to recreate the interface (see sample here http://cl.ly/3VAn ), using an undecorated window.

After many attempts I finally got the base of it, working on the Mac.
for image go to http://cl.ly/3VNU/ScreenshotMac.png

But in Windows and Ubuntu I get this strange margin.
for image go to http://cl.ly/3V4I/ScreenshotLinux.png

The window is a JFrame with three JPanels which have their paintComponent overrided.
Here is the compiled .jar, http://cl.ly/3VCG to try it yourselves.
If you think you need the source code, here it is http://cl.ly/3VSz .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the learning curve is simply too high to help you here.  You'd probably get more takers if you modified your question to include a list of the things you tried or checked.  Are you using a layout manager?  If so, which one?  Have you checked the bounds of each component?  What was the results of that test?  etc.

Comment: Your gui was created using a GUI builder.  You're going to need a lot of luck and time to modify that. Much better would be to build your GUI from scratch giving you much more control over its creation.

Comment: Yes we need source code because it is obviously a programming problem. But I am sure not going to look at a zip file to see your entire project. You need to isolate the problem. Once you isolate the problem you may even be able to solve it yourself. You isolate the problem by creating a SSCCE (http://sscce.org). If you can't solve the problem, then you have someting short and simple to post on the forum for use to look at.

Comment: Thank you all for replying! I forgot to mention that the interface was done with NetBeans Swing GUI Editor, but I altered the code. I didn't expect anyone to go through a whole source folder, I was just asking if this problem is a known issue (margins appearing in some platforms only) or where the problem might lie. I'll investigate the bounds for each component as per Erick's suggestion. Then if that doesn't work out, I'll either lay the panels out by hand or isolate the problem and come back. Thanks again for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. You only need one mouse handler for both panels. As this may needlessly complicate event handling in the tool bars, I'd let the OS do the decorating instead.
2. You should localize your background drawing.
3. You can use `setPreferredSize()` and override `getPreferredSize()` as needed.
4. Your `main()` method should build the GUI on "[*on the event dispatch thread.*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)"
5. The default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` with no gaps between components.

Here's an example that suggests some of the principles:

```
public class WelcomeWindow extends JFrame {

    private ToolPanel top = new ToolPanel("/guiresources/BgTop.png");
    private PaperPanel middle = new PaperPanel("/guiresources/BgPaper.png");
    private ToolPanel bottom = new ToolPanel("/guiresources/BgBottom.png");

    public WelcomeWindow() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() throws IOException {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setUndecorated(true);

        middle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
        top.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        top.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
        bottom.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        bottom.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        private Point point = new Point();

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            point.x = e.getX();
            point.y = e.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = getLocation();
            setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - point.x, p.y + e.getY() - point.y);
        }
    }
}

class PaperPanel extends JPanel {

    protected Image image;

    PaperPanel(String name) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(name));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}

class ToolPanel extends PaperPanel {

    ToolPanel(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I just logged in to report that after I redid the layout by hand (using BorderLayout) it all worked fine! Thanks a lot for your effort, tips and code! I wasn't done fiddling with it, to optimize it and re-use code, but your input is really high quality, I'll take a lot of it in! Thanks again!